# prevent UIButton Label not blinking when change label with Timer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to develop add counter value into UIButton label as following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let counterAttribute = Settings.changeButtonStyle(fullString: String(format: "Continue in %d secs", self.otpTimer) as NSString, boldPartsOfString: "Continue", changeFontString: "\(self.otpTimer)")
    self.continueButton.setAttributedTitle(counterAttribute, for: .normal)
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(self.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateTimer() {
    self.otpTimer = self.otpTimer - 1
    let counterAttribute = Settings.changeButtonStyle(fullString: String(format: "Continue in %d secs", self.otpTimer) as NSString, boldPartsOfString: "Continue", changeFontString: "\(self.otpTimer)")
    self.continueButton.setAttributedTitle(counterAttribute, for: .normal)
}
```

And change UIButton label function

```
static func changeButtonStyle(fullString: NSString, boldPartsOfString: String, changeFontString: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    let nonBoldFontAttribute = [
        NSFontAttributeName: MyFont.caption2,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: MyColor.white
    ]

    /* convert NSString to be added as NSMutableAttributedString */
    let changeThemeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullString as String, attributes: nonBoldFontAttribute)

    if boldPartsOfString.count > 0 {
        let boldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName: MyFont.subheading]
        changeThemeString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: fullString.range(of: boldPartsOfString))
    }

    if changeFontString.count > 0 {
        let colorFontAttribute = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: MyColor.darkPink]
        changeThemeString.addAttributes(colorFontAttribute, range: fullString.range(of: changeFontString))
    }

    return changeThemeString
}
```

Problem is whenever timer is changed, UIButton label is blinking. That's why I want to know how to make not blinking UIButton Label by changing above my code. Thanks.

Comment: Can you maybe attach a gif of what is happening?

Comment: Try to execute this code-> self.continueButton.setAttributedTitle(counterAttribute, for: .normal) in the main queue.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way how to fix it, We need to add `UIView.performWithoutAnimation` as well to prevent not to refresh UIView.

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
myTimer = myTimer - 1
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    /* Change UIButton Label */
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the title updates between these two calls:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
/// update button title
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```